# Numpy only on finite entries

Tags: python, numpy, nan

Here's a brief example of a function. It maps a vector to a vector. However, entries that are NaN or inf should be ignored. Currently this looks rather clumsy to me. Do you have any suggestions?

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

def p(vv):
    mask = np.isfinite(vv)
    y = np.NaN * vv
    v = vv[mask]

    y[mask] = 1/v*(stats.hmean(v)/len(v))
    return y
```

Comment: What problems do you have with the NaNs? Is your question "How to handle NaNs"? Your title isn't very clear.

Comment: I just want to learn more about them. I thought there is maybe a more elegant construction to operate only on the finite entries.

Comment: It might be off-topic as your question should be about a specific problem. For example, off-topic questions include "there is no actual problem to be solved: "I’m curious if other people feel like I do." see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)"

Answer (score 1):

You can change the NaN values to zero with Numpy's isnan function and then remove the zeros as follows:

```
import numpy as np

def p(vv):
    # assuming vv is your array
    # use Nympy's isnan function to replace the NaN values in the array with zero

     replace_NaN = np.isnan(vv)
     vv[replace_NaN] = 0

     # convert array vv to list
     vv_list = vv.tolist()
     new_list = []

     # loop vv_list and exclude 0 values:
      for i in vv_list:
          if i != 0:
              new.list.append(i)

      # set array vv again

      vv = np.array(new_list, dtype = 'float64')

      return vv
```

Answer (score 1):

I have came up with this kind of construction:

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np


## operate only on the valid entries of x and use the same mask on the resulting vector y
def __f(func, x):
    mask = np.isfinite(x)
    y = np.NaN * x
    y[mask] = func(x[mask])
    return y


# implementation of the parity function
def __pp(x):
    return 1/x*(stats.hmean(x)/len(x))


def pp(vv):
    return __f(__pp, vv)
```

Answer (score 1):

Masked arrays accomplish this functionality and allow you to specify the mask as you desire. The numpy 1.18 docs for it are here: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#what-is-a-masked-array

In masked arrays, False mask values are used in calculations, while True are ignored for calculations.

Example for obtaining the mean of only the finite values using `np.isfinite()`:

```
import numpy as np

# Seeding for reproducing these results
np.random.seed(0)

# Generate random data and add some non-finite values
x = np.random.randint(0, 5, (3, 3)).astype(np.float32)
x[1,2], x[2,1], x[2,2] = np.inf, -np.inf, np.nan
# array([[  4.,   0.,   3.],
#        [  3.,   3.,  inf],
#        [  3., -inf,  nan]], dtype=float32)

# Make masked array. Note the logical not of isfinite
x_masked = np.ma.masked_array(x, mask=~np.isfinite(x))

# Mean of entire masked matrix
x_masked.mean()
# 2.6666666666666665

# Masked matrix's row means
x_masked.mean(1)
# masked_array(data=[2.3333333333333335, 3.0, 3.0],
#              mask=[False, False, False],
#        fill_value=1e+20)

# Masked matrix's column means
x_masked.mean(0)
# masked_array(data=[3.3333333333333335, 1.5, 3.0],
#              mask=[False, False, False],
#        fill_value=1e+20)
```

Note that `scipy.stats.hmean()` also works with masked arrays.

Note that if all you care about is detecting NaNs and leaving `inf`s, then you can use `np.isnan()` instead of `np.isfinite()`.